# How to identify spark methods , its does not belong to either transformation and action

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to get the list of spark method , its does not belong to either transformation or action . Like say cache is neither transformation or action.

is there any way to identify method does not belong to either transformation or action ?

Thanks

Comment: `cache` is also a transformation. all methods that don't return RDD or Dataset are actions.

Comment: please read Jacek Laskowski answer  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44002128/when-are-cache-and-persist-executed-since-they-dont-seem-like-actions